# Android game LibGDX Box2D animation object

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

I'm developing game in LibGDX for Android with Box2D support. Now, I want to make my character running(it's a normal human) with 8 frame animation, but I'm not sure how to do this correctly. 
I have tought about two possibly options.
First option is to create 8 diffrent sprites and Box2D infos for this and then change it.
Second option to create separate object(head,body,arms,legs) and then to change position programmaticly. I personally think that second the option is better but I'm not sure how can I implment this.

Comment: libgdx has an Animation class, and a nice wiki tutorial. Did you check that out? [link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation)

Comment: Yes ofc, but I must maintain body from Box2D and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Maybe some more info is needed (or it is just me). I don't understand. Do you have 1 box2d body representing your character, if so, what info do you need to determine the animation frame? Or is your player a box2d ragdoll type structure with 8 different moving parts (fixtures) that each would have an image you want to draw based on running, or some other combo? I can't picture what you're trying to do/ask.